# PrimeFaces p:inputText and p:inputTextarea rendering too wide in a p:panelGrid form

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I have noticed that on our forms the input fields `p:inputText` and `p:inputTextarea` are rendered too wide compared to other widgets, e.g. `p:select*` or `p:commandButton`. Our forms are enclosed by a p:panelGrid.

Here's a test page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <title>
            D E B U G
        </title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:form>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                <p:outputLabel value="ID:" />
                <p:inputText style="width: 100%;" />

                <h:outputText />
                <p:commandButton value="all = width: 100%" style="width: 100%;" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Status:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu style="width: 100%;">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Status A" itemValue="1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Status B" itemValue="2" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Status C" itemValue="3" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel value="Remarks:" />
                <p:inputTextarea rows="6" style="width: 100%;" />

            </p:panelGrid>

            <br />

            <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                <p:outputLabel value="ID:" />
                <p:inputText style="width: 300px;" />

                <h:outputText />
                <p:commandButton value="all = width: 300px" style="width: 300px;" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Status:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu style="width: 300px;">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Status A" itemValue="1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Status B" itemValue="2" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Status C" itemValue="3" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel value="Remarks:" />
                <p:inputTextarea rows="6" style="width: 300px;" />

            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>        

    </h:body>

</html>
```

It looks like this on Firefox:

[image]

It looks like this on IE 9 (IE 8 mode):

[image]

For the percentage widths `<p:inputText style="width: 100%;" />`
, the components are rendered slightly too wide. The same seems to apply for the absolute widths `<p:inputText style="width: 300px;" />`.

I found out, that the PrimeFaces CSS comes with

```
.ui-inputfield {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

, where removing the padding results in the correct width. However, the padding is meant for the text inset of the inputs. Overriding the CSS selector doesn't really work.

**Qs**:

How do you fix the `p:inputText` and `p:inputText`? How do you best adjust for this? Using a custom PrimeFaces renderer?

Addendum:

I looked into the sources, but I couldn't find the place where this could be changed (InputRenderer class?). Any tips on where to look are appreciated (in a comment!).

Note that the `p:calendar` component seems to show the correct size (only for percentage widths however). PrimeFaces seems to have issues here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal behaviour, you've found out already why. Because of padding in the theme you've choosen.

So you can:

- adapt the width of your components properly. Use 296px for inputText or 304px for selectOneMenu or anything that fits your needs
- override the css style for given section. Just find out how to override the style for given class in given context.
- the best solution, because you have specific needs: **Write your own theme** based on current theme (PrimeFaces docu section 7).

Comment: How will #1 work for percentage widths? We're already using a theme switcher, so basically using our own, custom theme won't be a general solution for all other themes.

Answer (score 0):

You can override padding and other styles **after** primefaces stylesheet. Usually this means inline / include stylesheet directly after <h:body>:

```
.ui-inputfield {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: will you please help, how to change the color of pr:inputText